# Use of pipe symbol in Select clause

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way/use of putting pipe symbol `||` in `select` clause.

I have come across following query in one of the article(probably to concatenate two values), but when I try to use the same in my query I am getting syntax error.

```
select FirstName ||''|| LastName As CustomerName from Customer
```

Please correct if I am using wrong syntax.

Comment: I've never heard of using the pipe symbol, but if you want to concatenate two values like that use the + symbol. `select FirstName + ' ' + LastName As CustomerName from Customer` (I added a space for you though...so you are actually concatenating something visible :)

Comment: your query is oracle syntax, `||`translates to `+` in sql server

Comment: AFAIK, `||` is used in `Oracle`, not in `SQL-Server`.

Comment: `Oracle`, `MySql` and `DB2` use the pipes, `||`, but `SqlServer` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking whether you can use pipes `||` for concatenation in Microsoft SQL, then the short answer is no.

If you’re asking about the concatenation operator itself, then read on.

`||` is the standard ANSI concatenation operator. This is apparent in PostgreSQL, SQLite and Oracle, among others.

Microsoft, however uses `+`, because, why not. Except Microsoft Access uses `&`, because, why not.

MariaDB/MySQL have two modes. In traditional mode, `||` is interpreted as “or”, and there is no concatenation operator. In ANSI mode, `||` is interpreted as the concatenation operator.

Most DBMS (not SQLite) have the non-standard `concat()` function which will also concatenate. They also coalesce any `NULL`s to empty strings, so they’re a bit more forgiving if you don’t care about `NULL`s.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `CONCAT()` function, which works in SQL Server 2012 and above, or just a plain `+` sign to do concatenation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515(v=sql.110).aspx

> Returns a string that is the result of concatenating two or more
>   string values.

Answer (score 4):

you need to use '+' to perform Concat() instead of pipe if you are using SQL-Server. Pipe operator is not used in SQL-Server

Answer (score 2):

It is used to concatenate you columns and output a single result i.e in one column.
For example, if i want to see first name and last name together as in one column then i could use pipes:

```
SELECT Fname||Lname FROM my_table;
```

Comment: This syntax is not supported  in Microsoft SQL Server.